# Javascript to untag spans without id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would it be possible to find and untag spans that do not have ids within a string? I have a text that has bunch of spans some of which have ids and others don't.

Input:

```
<span>Hi there!</span><span id="blabla">This is a test</span>
```

Output:

```
Hi there!<span id="blabla">This is a test</span>
```

I prefer JavaScript functions but  I wouldn't mind using jQuery if it makes things easier!

Comment: how do you pronounce your 'name' using only latin characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use a combination of the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) pseudo-selector, and a "[has-attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)" selector:

```
$("span:not([id])").contents().unwrap();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/Hfs7C/1/). Notice how the HTML code is made up of 4 `span` elements, the CSS rule applies to all `span` elements, but does not apply to the 2 `span` elements without an `id`, because they have been unwrapped by the above jQuery.

The [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method returns all of the children of the selected elements, and [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) removes the parent, which in this case will be the unwanted `span`.

Comment: how can I use it inside of an ordinary JavaScript Function?

Comment: As in, without jQuery at all?

Comment: Yes. I would like to be able to use it inside of a JS function.

Comment: @ЭџadДьdulяңмaи: You probably know this, but, just in case: jQuery is just a set of utilities (all under the `jQuery`/`$` variable). You can absolutely use it from inside a JavaScript function, as long as jQuery exists on the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span").each(function(){
    if (this.id == "") $(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qDR32/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span").each(function (i) {

 if (this.id == '') {

  alert('no have id');

 } else {

  alert('have id');
 }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery this would be very straightforward.

```
$(function(){
    $('span').each(function(){
        if(typeof $(this).attr('id') == "undefined"){
            $(this)[0].outerHTML = $(this).html();
        }
    });
});
```

See working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rD3tn/)..

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
input = '<span>Hi there!</span><span id="blabla">This is a test</span>';

output = $( '<div>' ).html( input ).children().each( function () {
   !this.id && $( this ).replaceWith( $( this ).text() );
}).end().html();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3EXkh/3/

---

**Update:** The above code in function-form:

```
function untag( input ) {
    return $( '<div>' ).html( input ).children().each( function () {
       !this.id && $( this ).replaceWith( $( this ).text() );
    }).end().html();
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3EXkh/4/

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a pure-JavaScript solution, FWIW:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(el.getElementsByTagName('span'), function(element){
    var children;
    if( ! element.id){
        children = document.createDocumentFragment();
        while(element.firstChild){
            children.appendChild(element.firstChild);
        }
        element.parentElement.replaceChild(children, element);
    }
});
```

Making this work in browsers which don’t have `Array.prototype.forEach` is left as en exercise for the reader.